# watir headless test runs fine on local linux but errors out on headless linux box

Tags: linux, watir, headless

I am using watir headless to run basic login test case on my website. It works well from my machine (normal dev linux machine) but fails with following error on a headless linux server (using firefox):

script:

Thanks for response. I tried using when_present, and it never returns true and script timeouts. This script works fine on linux dev machine with ui but fails at'browser.text_field(:name, "memberForm.memberpassword").set("password")' on a linux server.

Following is the script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start
begin
browser = Watir::Browser.start 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/login'
browser.text_field(:name, "memberForm.memberemail").set("tester")
puts browser.text_field(:name, "memberForm.memberpassword")
browser.text_field(:name, "memberForm.memberpassword").set("password")
browser.button(:id, "login-button").click
puts browser.text
if(resultText.include?'Error Message')
   puts 'login failed'  
else
  puts 'success'
end

rescue => e
    puts e.message
    p e.backtrace
ensure
    browser.close
    headless.destroy
end
```

Error is:

```
 [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20121231-18379-1ad5l77/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:6771:in `unknown': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
 <fieldset id="login-form-fieldset">

             <div class="clearfix">
                 <input class="span5"
                        id="memberForm_memberemail_id"
                        name="memberForm.memberemail"
                        type="text"                        
                        value="<gs:property value="memberForm.memberemail" escape="false"/>"/>
             </div>

             <div class="clearfix">
                 <input class="span5"
                        id="memberForm_memberpassword_id"
                        name="memberForm.memberpassword"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password" />
             </div>

             <gs:token />

            <div class="clearfix">
                <button type="submit" id="login-button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Login</button>

                <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    Forgot Password? <a href="<gs:url action="forgot-password" namespace="/" />">Click here</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
</div>
```

I don't understand what is going wrong on headless linux server? If I don't try to set value to password field it works fine and goes to Forgot password page.

Comment: HTML is incomplete in question but it is not using frames at all. plain divs and input. <input id="memberForm_memberemail_id"
                        name="memberForm.memberemail"
                        type="text"                       
                        />
             </div>
             
             <div class="clearfix">
                 <input             id="memberForm_memberpassword_id"
                        name="memberForm.memberpassword"
                        type="password" />
             </div>

Comment: Can you log in on the server manually? Are you sure exactly the same app (and version) opens when you go to 127.0.0.1:8080 at your machine and at the server?

Comment: it was problem of the particular machine. The script works perfectly well on different linux headless (non-gui) machine. It isn't problem anymore. 
Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says `Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`. That sounds like there is a problem with the script, not with the machine. The element is not visible when the script tries to interact with it.

There is documentation on how to wait for element: http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

If you provide relevant code, somebody could know more.